# Django redirect call appends package name to url

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am writing a view for editing a title in django (at `'project_edit.html'`, and redirecting to the `'project_detail.html'` page, but (loosely) following the tutorial [here](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/README.html) I'm using the redirect method:

```
def project_edit(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project_update = form.save(commit=False)
            project.title = project_update.title
            project.save()
            return redirect(to='gantt_charts.views.project_detail', kwargs={'pk', project.pk}, permanent=True)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Form invalid!")
            return render(request, 'project_edit.html', {'project':project, 'form':form})
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'project_edit.html', {'project':project, 'form':form})
```

In the tutorial, they also use redirect:

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

But when I click my link `http://localhost:8000/project/2/edit` and submit my form, I get sent to: `http://localhost:8000/project/2/gantt_charts.views.project_detail`

I cannot fathom why.

Looking at the `redirect` definition in shortcuts.py and then the `resolve_url` definition, my only guess is that it drops to the bottom and it just returned as is. Why isn't the lookup performed?

ed:

Here are my url patterns for that app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^(?:project)?/?$', views.project_list), 
    url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/edit$', views.project_edit), 
    url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/[A-z\\-]{0,50}$', views.project_detail), 
    )
```

Comment: Well, if it doesn't match `to` a url pattern, it assumes it's an actual URL. So what do your urlpatterns look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added them in. Is it my optional 50 word slug that's messing things up?

Comment: No: but that that URL takes a `project_id` kwarg, not `pk`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman good point. D'oh, I've fixed that and followed the advice in [Catavaran](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28041999/1075247)'s answer. It works. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a name to your project detail url:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/[A-z\\-]{0,50}$',
                       views.project_detail, name='project_detail`),
```

And then refer to this name in `redirect()` call:

```
return redirect('project_detail', project_id=project.pk, permanent=True)
```

Comment: Awesome. I changed pk to project_id, like @DanielRoseman suggested. What was it doing before?